# What Firewall, anti DDOS and anti Brute-Force managers exist in Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, security, firewall

I have heard of `ufw` and of course using `iptables` but is there any other firewall or port manager for incoming/outgoing connections. I am also looking for GUI based ones apart from terminal ones and a bonus for any tool used to help in the DDOS attacks and automatic banning that come with Ubuntu. Not talking server only but desktop too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of firewall tools, there are several graphical front ends, depending on your needs.

gufw is a graphical front end for ufw.

And there is also firestarter, which is popular.

Automatic banning can be done with several tools, iptables, denyhosts, and fail2ban.

I suggest you look at fail2ban.

DDOS attacks can not be stopped, you can set some limits with ufw and iptables.

http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/prevent-dos-with-iptables/

Those tools should get you started in short order, let us know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend OSSEC; though I have only used it for servers I do not see why it would not work on the desktop. While it is not GUI based it will adjust your firewall to respond to 'detected' attacks. If you need a GUI you could load a web front end for it, but that would actually open another hole on the machine as you would be running  web server.

http://www.ossec.net/

Front End:
BASE">http://www.ossec.net/wiki/index.php/OSSEC&_BASE

OSSEC is an Open Source Host-based Intrusion Detection System. It performs log analysis, file integrity checking, policy monitoring, rootkit detection, real-time alerting and active response.

---

Comment: Hello cprofit, imagine seeing you here.

Comment: ossec isn't a firewall or portmanager and isn't -gui based.

Answer (score 1):

A list of debian based firewalls are found here: http://wiki.debian.org/Firewalls. Some with a -gui, guarddog for example.
Watch and see how many firewalls/ -gui based firewalls are not maintained anymore, except some website updates. The same with firestarter, there are some nasty security bugs related to firestarter. I would not recommend firestarter as a -gui based firewall because it isn't maintained.
One example: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firestarter/+bug/42759